# Change attribute within a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I could not find an answer to it. I was unable to find a way to put my question without an example. 
Imagine I have  table with hundreds of rows. Now on each of these rows I have a selectbox:

```
<select id="task_stat" name="task[stat]" style="display: none;"></select>
```

Options are not a concern now (I have a few in my actual file). Now all of these select boxes have the same `id` field. I was wondering how can I change display of only one select box when it's corresponding `<tr>` is clicked on. I have the following:

```
$("#myTableId tr").click(function() {
    $("select #task_stat").css("display"),"block");
});
```

Of course withing a `$(document).ready` function. But that will display all select boxes (as expected) and not only one. Is there a way to display only the select box on the clicked table row? (I would really like it if it could be clicked `<td>` but I don't think `<td>` supports `.click`

Comment: You should NEVER have elements that have the same `id`. Elements can share the same `class` but `id`s need to always be unique.

Comment: Generated by rails and I really do not understand why they allow such an error in their framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't have duplicate `id` fields, use classes instead. Second, you should be able to change your function something like this, that references child elements of the `tr` that was clicked on:

```
$("#myTableId tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children("select .task_stat").css("display","block");
});
```

This would assume that you changed your markup to be like this:

```
<select class="task_stat" name="task[stat]" style="display: none;"></select>
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments below, this is likely nested beyond the direct descendants of the `tr`, so it would be more appropriate to use `find()` instead of `children()`:

```
$("#myTableId tr").click(function() {
    $(this).find("select .task_stat").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: If your select element is not a direct descendant of the `<tr>` then use `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

Comment: Thanks very good answer. I have to have the same id since it's generated by rails `form_for` . I'll look for a way to assign a class using rails.

Answer (score 1):

ID's should always be unique. That's the whole point behind them. If you have multiple elements, try using a class name if you need a hook.

If these inputs are getting generated server-side, via a loop or something, see if you can append the loop iterator or something to the id. For example, "mySelect1".

[Check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/8TD5b/2/) It should get you going in the right direction.

Something along these lines is the javascript you need:

```
$('table td').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Dude you are a legend. This was exactly what I wanted with a little bit of change. I already accepted another answer but this is great. I assigned a class to my elements from the server but didn't change their id since rails uses that id to save them into database